# List comprehension IF OR Condition

Tags: python

When evaluate the `x != '0'` or `x != '-1'`, the compiler return the intended output.

```
opt=[f'xt:{x}' for x in status if x != '0']
```

OR

```
opt=[f'xt:{x}' for x in status if  x !='-1']
```

The issue arise when I combine the  `x != '0' or x !='-1'` together.

```
status = ['-1', '2', '3', '0']
opt=[f'xt:{x}' for x in status if x != '0' or x !='-1']
```

> ```
> ['xt:-1', 'xt:2', 'xt:3', 'xt:0']
> ```

But, I expect the output to be

> `opt=['xt2','xt3']`

Comment: You should use `and`, not `or`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `x != '0' **and** x !='-1'`. I know what you mean in "humanspeak"-
neither 0 nor -1, but for a computer, that's "not 0, or not -1". So -1 is ok, because it's not 0, and the computer is satisfied. So all you need to do is change that `or` to an `and`.

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you switch the 'or statement' to an 'and statement' because the 'or statement' always evaluates to true in this case.